# how to display full details regarding the $id?

Tags: php, sql

I have a form for user to submit their inquiry. after submitting the form, the data will go to php file and it will connect to the database. right now, I have the problem with the update.php . technically update.php will show a full details of the user personal info regarding of their id when the 'kemaskini' button is clicked in the admin.php.

but what happened here, the code displayed it like this, example, when I click Lily, Lily detail will be displayed. but when I click Julia, Lily detail would be displayed again. it would produce only Lily detail :(

admin.php

```
<tr>
        <th>NO</th>
        <th>NAMA PEMOHON</th>
        <th>UNIT/JABATAN/&nbsp;<br>BAHAGIAN</th>
        <th>NO.TELEFON</th>
        <th>E-MAIL</th>
        <th>DATA/LAPORAN YANG DIPOHON</th>
        <th>TUJUAN</th>
        <th>TINDAKAN</th>
        <th>AGIHAN</th>
        <th>KEMASKINI</th>
    </tr>   

<tbody>
<?php
include('config.php');

    $bil = 0;
    //$option = '';
    $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pemohon");
    //$option .='<select>';
    //$count=mysql_num_rows($results);
    //
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
    $bil++;



    echo "<form name='update $bil' action=update.php method=post>"; ?>
    <tr>
        <td><center><?php echo $bil; ?></center></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['unit']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['telefon']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['data']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['tujuan']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['tindakan']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['agihan']; ?></td>
        <td><input type='submit' name='submit' value='kemaskini'>
            <input type='hidden' name='id' value=<?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
    </tr>

<?php 
}
?>
```

update.php

```
 <?php
    include('config.php');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM pemohon WHERE id='".$_POST['id']."'";
    $results = mysql_query($sql);

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($results);
    //$user = $row['username'];


    $id = $row['id'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $jawatan = $row['jawatan'];
    $unit = $row['unit'];
    $kementerian = $row['kementerian'];
    $telefon = $row['telefon'];
    $faks = $row['faks'];
    $email = $row['email'];
    $data = $row['data'];
    $tujuan = $row['tujuan'];
    $tarikh = $row['tarikh'];
    $tindakan = $row['tindakan'];

    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $submit = $_POST['submit'];
    ?>

    <form name="update" action="update2.php" method="post">
        <table width="763" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td>No. ID</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td><?php echo "$id"; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="173">Nama Pemohon</td>
                <td width="10">:</td>
                <td width="564"><?php echo "$name"; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jawatan</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td><?php echo "$jawatan"; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Unit/Jabatan/Bahagian</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td><?php echo "$unit"; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Kementerian/Institusi/Agensi</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td><?php echo "$jawatan"; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>No. Telefon</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td><?php echo "$telefon"; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>No. Faks</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td><?php echo "$faks"; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>E-mail</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td><?php echo "$email"; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data/Laporan Yang Dipohon</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td><?php echo "$data"; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tujuan</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td><?php echo "$tujuan"; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tarikh Permohonan</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td><?php echo "$tarikh"; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tindakan</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td><label>
                    <select name="tindakan" id="tindakan">
                    <option selected="selected"></option>
                    <option>Diluluskan</option>
                    <option>Tidak Diluluskan</option>
                    </select>
                    </label>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Agihan</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td><label>
                    <select name="agihan" id="agihan">
                    <option selected="selected"></option>
                    <option>Pn. Suryana Binti Embong</option>
                    <option>Pn. Rohaida Binti Ali</option>
                    <option>En. Hasril Rezuan Bin Suboh</option>
                    </select>
                    </label>
            </tr>

    <p align="center">
    <input type="hidden" name="noid" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">
    <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Kemaskini" />

    </p>
    </form>
```

Comment: In admin.php do you have multiple forms or it just a single form?

Comment: wait, the question is about displaying but why am i seeing update here. second is because you're submitting the form again so it will produce 1 user unless if you append the result in your DOM

Comment: @cyberboy single I guess? actually, admin.php is the page where some of the user details is displayed in the table. form.php is originally the form where the user submit their details.

Comment: @DrixsonOseña because the page contain update section in there. and its linked to the update2.php :)

Comment: @DrixsonOseña second....how exactly to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In admin.php you missed a closing ">" in INPUT tag.

```
<input type='hidden' name='id' value=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>
```

should be

```
<input type='hidden' name='id' value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
```

So the hidden input is not closed, not sent by the browser, so the $_POST['id'] is empty and mayby this is why you get all the time the same record with empty id.

Good practice is to always use "" for values. With them you will see clearly if the tag was closed and you will avoid problems with values with spaces.

Comment: change it :) and still get the same record :(

Comment: and what about the closing </form> tag? If you don't have it, than you produce code like this:
<form><submit><input id=1> <form><submit><input id=2> <form><submit><input id=3> and the browser can get a little crazy about those nested forms using always the last <input id=3> :)

Comment: OMG. it's working! thank you so much! sorry for the silly syntax. thank you sir! :D

Comment: You're welcome :) And don't use mysql, use mysqli or PDO. [This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)